# How do I clean the intake filter for my washing mashine?

Tags: cleaning, washing-machine, filter

I have the [Novamatic WA 1268.3 Aqua Stop](https://www.fust.ch/de/p/haushalt/waschmaschinen-und-waeschetrockner/waschmaschinen-einfamilienhaushalt/waschmaschinen-etage/novamatic/wa-1268-3-aq-st-neu-104984.html) washing machine, and there is a fault that says I have to clean the filter in the pipe that brings water to the machine because the machine is apparently not getting enough water.

However, the ring around that filter is not like the book says it is.

This is what I have:
[image: This is what I have]

And this is what the book depicts:
[image: What the book depicts]

How do I open this copper ring around the pipe ending to clean the filter inside?

The filter inside:[image: filter inside]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's brass, not copper, and it looks to me like a typical hose fitting with a pressed-in rubber washer.

Try grasping the washer with a needle-nose pliers and pulling it out. My guess is that the screen will follow. If the washer is damaged or worn it can probably be replaced with an inexpensive part from a hardware or garden store.

Comment: I agree it is probably a standard hose washer . possibly an O ring +